# replace JSON file everytime I do JSON.stringify for a new one (refreshing every key and value)

Tags: node.js, json, express

I'm trying to scrape a page and create a JSON with the obtained values. The problem is that everytime I call the **scraping** fuction for refreshing prices for example, it does Json.strigify and  concat everything on the JSON insted of replace the file.

I would like to have a new Json with the same file name overwriting the first one.

```
Promise.all(promises).then((results) => {
    console.log(results);
    let clothesJson = JSON.stringify(results);
    fs.writeFileSync('../src/coldW.json', clothesJson, 'utf-8');
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Promise.all(promises)
  .then((results) => {
    console.log(results);
    let clothesJson = JSON.stringify(results);
    fs.unlinkSync("../src/coldW.json");
    fs.writeFileSync("../src/coldW.json", clothesJson, "utf-8");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

just delete the file and write it again